# Thesis chapter headings, any suggestions?

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I've found a thesis with really beautiful chapter headings that I would like to use. What package am I going to need and how would I go about creating a heading that looks like the one below. Also, if you have or know of any nice headings do please share!
[image: chapter heading]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think that an MWE is appropriate for this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an option using the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package:

[image: screenshot]

I've used the general format of the `titleformat` command:

```
% from the titlesec package
%\titleformat{ command }
%             [ shape ]
%             { format }{ label }{ sep }{ before-code }[ after-code ]
```

You can find more information by studying the documentation, and by viewing other similar questions on this site.

Here's a complete MWE to play with:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% title format for the chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\bfseries\large}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\titlerule[3pt]~\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\sc{\chaptername}~\thechapter}~\titlerule[3pt]%
            \\\vspace{.05cm}\titlerule\\\filcenter #1 \\\vspace{.25cm}\titlerule}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

You mention that you might like to see other ideas; here's another one, again using the `titlesec` package but without the `explicit` option - I have used the `tcolorbox` package to put a box around the chapter number. I don't know if I'd recommend it for a thesis, but it might give you some further ideas:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

% title format for the chapter
% custom chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
{}                                                      % label
{1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
    % draw a box around the chapter number
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=1.4pt,
            colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2.8cm]
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}\Huge} % before the title body
[]                        % after the title body
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good, but this adds numbering to the preface, contents, and index by default. What should I do?

Comment: @albo I'd recommend a new question, with a small, complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Okay sir, I did.