# Get a section title style in beamer class to work in article class

Tags: beamer, sectioning, titles, tcolorbox, article

I would like to use the style of title given by the following code in article class. Some amendments to the code will have to be made, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I'd be grateful of some help on this, thanks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{colourchange}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%      pour les maths
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\sectiontitlepage}[1]{
\selectmanualcolour{#1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
    title=\sc Part \thesection, center title,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=#1!50!white,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1!50!black,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
    interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)-- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)-- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)-- cycle;}}
]
   \center\LARGE\textcolor{black}{\secname}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\section{A part}
\sectiontitlepage{white}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do in `article` exactly? What have you tried? Don't use macros which are 20+ years obsolete in LaTeX, such as `\sc`.

Comment: Assuming this code has another author and source, please attribute it and provide a link. Not only is this possibly required, it is only common courtesy and, besides, helps people trying to help you enormously if they have queries about the original context and usage.

Comment: https://thehatteronline.com/2014/09/17/fancier-beamer-presentations/

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194601/36296 it customises a chapter heading including a `tcolorbox`